# Making python blackjack code more efficent

Tags: python, simulation, blackjack

I wrote a piece of blackjack code - for dealer dealing cards to himself (python). My question is how can I make it more efficient, faster and neater. I ran it for 1.000.000 iterations and it took 14.7 second which is quite slow, I believe.

```
import random
deck = 4 * [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11]
random.shuffle(deck)


dealer_hand = []
dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
hit_on_soft_17 = True
exit = False

while not exit:
    if sum(dealer_hand) == 17 and hit_on_soft_17:
        exit = True
        for i, card in enumerate(dealer_hand):
            if card == 11:
                exit = False
                dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
                break
    if sum(dealer_hand) < 17:
        exit = False
        dealer_hand.append(deck.pop(0))
    if sum(dealer_hand) > 21: 
        exit = True
        for i, card in enumerate(dealer_hand):
            if card == 11:
                exit = False
                dealer_hand[i] = 1
                break
    if sum(dealer_hand) < 22 and sum(dealer_hand) > 17:
        exit = True

print(dealer_hand)
```

Comment: I guess  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question than StackOverflow.

Comment: You don't need to set `exit = False` since it's already explicitly `False` when the while loop starts and it's literally the while condition. Otherwise I would consider breaking up your code into more explicit logical constructs. Example, `while not exit` works, but if that's the case then you're basically going to draw another card and consider if you want to exit. You should be using `if`/ `elif` / `else` instead of a series of `if` statements. All of that said, the code isn't terribly inefficient for it's purpose so other than restructuring for readability I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: pop(0) is bad on lists, instead consider python [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), a pop(0) on list causes the entire list to be copied backwards, which is slow. this doesn't happen in deque.

Comment: Instead of a deque, you could also pop from the end of the array (instead of the beginning) with `.pop()`, which is significantly faster than `.pop(0)`

Comment: i have tried all suggested modifications, and nothing reduced the time by more than 1%, it seems the bottleneck is the python interpreter itself, so converting it to cython, or c++ is the only way to speed it.

Comment: if you are running millions of them, then this is an embarrassingly parallel problem where if you have 8 cores for example you can make it run 8-16 times faster using the multiprocessing module, something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few changes. First, dealing from the end of the array instead of the beginning is faster, so I've changed all `pop` statements accordingly. I've also neatened up the check for a soft 17, removed redundant `exit = False` statements, and replaced `if`s with `elif`s.

```
import random
deck = 4 * [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11]
random.shuffle(deck)


dealer_hand = []
dealer_hand.append(deck.pop())
dealer_hand.append(deck.pop())
hit_on_soft_17 = True
exit = False

while not exit:
    if sum(dealer_hand) == 17 and hit_on_soft_17:
        if 11 in dealer_hand:
            dealer_hand.append(deck.pop())
        else:
            exit = True
    elif sum(dealer_hand) < 17:
        dealer_hand.append(deck.pop())
    elif sum(dealer_hand) > 21: 
        for i, card in enumerate(dealer_hand):
            if card == 11:
                dealer_hand[i] = 1
                break
        else:
            exit = True
    elif sum(dealer_hand) < 22 and sum(dealer_hand) > 17:
        exit = True

print(dealer_hand)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your performance are your `if` clauses and `for` loops.
A step in the right direction would be to use `elif`. If you use 3.10 or higher this is a good use case for Structural Pattern Matching (SPM). In > 3.10 you can use `match` & `case`. You may also not need some of the for loops. The first one can be reduced to `if 11 in dealer_hand`... But since your list size is only ever 2, this won't do much.

Edit: Since you are looking for the ace in your if statements it might make sense to keep the dealer hand `sorted`. With 11 being the largest expectable value, you'd know it's always at index `0` / `1` in descending / ascending order.